# New to OOP, how do I set a classes public variables to a global variable for use in static methods?

Tags: php, oop

I wrote a class to set and expire browser cookies. I'm trying to set the classes public variables to the value of a global variable in a way that would allow me to use the classes methods statically. Basically all I want to do is remove the duplicate global `$settings`, and the `$expire` and `$domain` variables.

Here's my code as it sits:

```
<?php

    class cookies {
        public static function set($name, $value, $date = false) {
            global $settings;

            $expire = ($date) ? $date : $settings['expire'];
            $domain = str_replace('www.', '', $settings['domain']);
            setcookie($name, $value, $expire, '/', $domain);
        }

        public static function clear() {
            global $settings;

            $domain = str_replace('www.', '', $settings['domain']);
            setcookie('test1', '', 1, '/', $domain);
            setcookie('test2', '', 1, '/', $domain);
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: If you're going to use a class statically - [use static class variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: Yes, but I can't set them to something like `$settings['expire']`, that's my problem.

Comment: Neither global variables nor static methods are part of OOP paradigm.

Comment: best approach make them non-static, make a constructor either pass the setting value when you instantiate the class or the way you want and set it to a member variable and access across the class

Comment: is your `$settings` dynamic? or comes from a config file?

Comment: `$settings` isn't dynamic, however, I want the expiration date to be adjustable if set, and if not set fallback to the default in the settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Using global variables is very bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions) for the flexibility, modularity and sanity of your app. [Using static method is very bad](http://kunststube.net/static/) for the modularity and flexibility of your app. Using both together is an abomination. How about you write a class that can be used like this:

```
$cookies = new Cookies($settings['expire'], $settings['domain']);
$cookies->set(.., .., ..);
$cookies->clear();
```

You'd start with a proper class structure like this:

```
class Cookies {

    protected $expire,
              $domain;

    public function __construct($expire, $domain) {
        $this->expire = $expire;
        $this->domain = $domain;
    }

    ...

}
```

Then you use `$this->expire` and `$this->domain` instead of global variables.

Comment: Thanks! I'll avoid statics and globals from now on ;)